# How build face geometry in threeJS from scaledMesh of detected face using tensorflow in js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, web, three.js

I want to create Geometry of a detected face in **ThreeJS**.
I'm using **Tensorflow** library to detect faces.

but when i use the BufferGeometry to create the Geometry of a detected face, the results are not same as i want.

[image]

**this is the code for creating geometry of detected face:**

(*TRIANGULATION is the scaledMesh property of detected face object*)

```
const verticesArr = new Float32Array(TRIANGULATION);
const geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const bufferAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(verticesArr, 3);
geo.setAttribute("position", bufferAttribute);
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Did you use `TRIANGULATION = predictions[i].scaledMesh` to generate the face landmarks data? Please update your questions with enough details for the community to be able to help you. The root problem is these points in `TRIANGULATION` are ill generated. Please paste the code which is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

Three.Mesh requires  the array of points `geo` to form a triangler mesh. According to your screen shot, the data generated by tensorflow seems to be point cloud. Thus, [Three.Points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points) is the proper visualization class.

```
const points = new THREE.Points( geo, mat);
```

If you have to draw a surface mesh,
There are various algorithms to generate mesh from poin cloud.

Comment: Can you describe more about that? (if it possible for you correct the code i'v wrote above and send). cause i couldn't fix that with your solution.

Comment: @Mirror Firstly replace `THREE.Mesh` with `THREE.Points`. If you see a cloud of points that resemble the expected face, it means your data  `TRIANGULATION` contain the right collection of points. Next step would be to generate a Tri mesh out of them. For example,  MeshLib implements a few of such algorithms.